# Count and filter with Group By; and Rows to Columns conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have two Tables

1. Task
2. TaskDetail

Task:

```
| TaskName |Department|TaskStatus|DetailID  |
|--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |
| T1       | D1       | 31       | 1        |
| T1       | D2       | 32       | 2        |
| T1       | D3       | 31       | 3        |
```

- Task 【T1】 is assigned to three departments 【D1, D2, D3】
- Each department has a different DeatilID for each task.
- there can be at most three TaskStatus: 30,31,32

TaskDetail:

```
|DetailID | AssetCode    | CodeStatus    |
|-------  |------------  |------------   |
| 1       | AC1          | 14            |
| 1       | AC2          | 14            |
| 1       | AC3          | 15            |
| 1       | AC4          | 16            |
| 1       | AC5          | 14            |
| 1       | AC6          | 16            |
| 2       | AC7          | 16            |
| 2       | AC8          | 16            |
| 2       | AC9          | 16            |
| 2       | AC10         | 16            |
| 2       | AC11         | 16            |
| 3       | AC10         | 15            |
| 3       | AC11         | 14            |
```

- TaskDetail has different asset codes for each department
- There can be at most three CodeStatus: 14, 15, 16

Desired Results:

```
| Row_ID   | TaskName |Department|TaskStatus|DetailID   |Count(14) |Count(15) |Count(16) |
|--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |--------- |
| 1        | T1       | D1       | 31       | 1        | 3        | 1        | 2        |
| 2        | T1       | D2       | 30       | 2        | 0        | 0        | 5        |
| 3        | T1       | D3       | 32       | 3        | 0        | 1        | 1        |
```

- TaskStatus is based on the CodeStatuses in TaskDetail Table

  ```
    if(count(16) = all) then TaskStatus 30;                 //as in Row_ID 2
    if(count(14)>=0 || count(15)>=0) then TaskStatus 31;    //as in Row_ID 1
    if(count(16)==0) then TaskStatus 32;                    //as in Row_ID 3
  ```
- The same CodeStatus are counted for each department based on the TaskName and placed in the columns Count(14), Count(15), and Count(16). For instance:

  ```
    Count(14)= Count of all CodeStatus = 14 
    Count(15)= Count of all CodeStatus = 15 
    Count(16)= Count of all CodeStatus = 16
  ```

Comment: Search the forum by `pivot [mysql]`.

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I think the numbers are wrong for task 3 in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is conditional aggregation with a `JOIN`:

```
select t.taskname, t.Department, t.TaskStatus, t.DetailID,
       sum(td.CodeStatus = 14) as num_14,
       sum(td.CodeStatus = 15) as num_15,
       sum(td.CodeStatus = 16) as num_16
from task t join
     taskdetail td
     using (DetailID)
group by t.taskname, t.Department, t.TaskStatusk, t.DetailID
```